# Rigged Hair (non-particle) Distorted by Armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, weight-painting

With the model I've made for my game, I've finished rigging it and everything but now I've run into a problem:

My character has two thick bracelets(one on each wrist) one on the upper right arm/bicep and some shoes(the left one has a band/anklet above it)

Now the issue is, when I move the upper right arm, the bands follow properly but when I move the right forearm, the upper band bends as if it's attached to it but after checking the weight paint section(which I don't use much and I'm still getting used to) it doesn't look like it's attached and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I have the same issue with the shoes too, when I rotate the legs, the shoes stay where they are and don't follow the model at all.

I can upload screenshots but due to copyright, I will not upload the model, thank you for understanding:

[![Property of CraftyMaelyss][1]][1]

[![Property of CraftyMaelyss][2]][2]

See what I mean? Also I took some screenshots of the weight paint and since I can't add more to the question, here's links to them:

http://sta.sh/21whv1rhxhpr?edit=1

Again, I'm not that experienced with weight painting but I've followed a few tutorials and it does seem to be working :(

Here's an example of one of the tutorials I tried:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBS1qy4jzTg

If there's another way to get these accessories to function properly, please let me know. In an older version of the model, all the accessories, clothes and such were separate objects but in this newest version of the model, it's all one object.

Comment: please upload your blend file to get analized

Comment: when uploading, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @CraftyMaelyss without uploading, there is just one answer: your armature is influencing that part of the mesh, for sure. if you can't find where, you could try using  "custom weight paint range" setting in preferences, to better highlight weights on the mesh... btw, I was about to add an answer, but I fear of answers thieves, they would just copy my answer, and make it theirs... 8-s

Comment: @m.ardito When you have someone steal you're model and try to sell it, you wouldn't be laughing about it.

Comment: sorry, that was not a laugh, it was disappointment. imho, had you uploaded the file, below you would have found answers fixing your model minutes later...

Comment: If I could privately upload so one person could check it, then it'd be less worry for theft since if it did appear for sale somewhere I'd be able to find the thief immediately if they did P: